# Django Google api client library oauth2client - Unresolved reference FlowField

Tags: django, google-api, django-rest-framework, google-oauth

In google api client documentation, an example is provided for using the api-client-library in django [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django)

I attempt to use the snippet provided as is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from oauth2client.contrib.django_orm import FlowField

class FlowModel(models.Model):
  id = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
  flow = FlowField()
```

Importing `from oauth2client.contrib.django_orm import FlowField` however produces an error in PyCharm:

> Unresolved reference FlowField

Looking into the github repository for [googleapis/oauth2client](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client) I am unable to find any reference to FlowField

What am I doing wrong?

(I have already installed the requirements with pip and have a running django application)

Answer (score 3):

As per this link: https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> **oauth2client is now deprecated.** No more features will be added to the libraries and the core team is turning down support. We recommend you use [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/) and [oauthlib](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/). For more details on the deprecation, see oauth2client deprecation.

Also see the following GitHub conversation:
https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/issues/686#issuecomment-268083225

To use OAuth with Django perhaps consider using the [`django-oauth-toolkit`](http://dot.evonove.it/) library:

- https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit
- https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

As noted above, this library is marked as deprecated, but you can run the following command to fix it:

```
$ pip install --upgrade oauth2client
```